# The lack of QJsonArray in PyQt

Tags: python, json, qt, pyqt5

Probably, this class was not required for the reason that the lists cope with other tasks well. Now this code:

```
def append_message_file(self, messages):
    """Adds new messages to a file"""
    history = QFile('soul.json')
    if history.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly):
        document = QJsonDocument().fromJson(history.readAll())
        array = document.array()
        history.close()
    else:
        array = []
    for index in range(len(messages['user'])):
        value = QJsonValue(messages['user'][index] + ': ' + messages['message'][index])
        array.append(value.toString())
    document = QJsonDocument(array)
    if history.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly):
        history.write(document.toJson(QJsonDocument.Indented))
        history.close()


messages = { 'user': [], 'message': [] }
messages['user'].append('asw')
messages['message'].append('How are you?')
self.append_message_file(messages)
```

Now soul.json:

```
[
    "asw: Hi!"
]
```

The above code must do a simple thing: take from the "history" file information in the JSON format, add it to the "document", then add one or more values ​​to the array of this document and write it to a file.
Everything is good without QJsonDocument. But if I have messages on several lines, then it's not enough to write such messages without quotes. It would seem that nothing should happen when this class begins to be used.

However, the first problem is the lack of QJsonArray in the PyQt5.QtCore module. Then I add the values ​​of QJsonValue to the normal list, and then to QJsonDocument. But this works only if there was no data in the file before. If they were, the Segmentation Fault error pops up.

Are there any ways to eliminate this or, in general, any ideas on conservation?

Comment: Why don't you just use the python json module? I would only use the qt classes if an api absolutely required them.

Comment: @ekhumoro Most likely, I will. I'm just wondering why I'm having a segmentation error. Thank you.

Comment: @ClimentiyTitov provide a [mcve], show `messages` and `soul.json`

Comment: @ClimentiyTitov I just noticed that you're trying to directly ***append*** one document to another. That is not going to work in any implementation of json. You need to add the new entries to an existing document (using [setArray](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#setArray)), and then overwrite the old document.

Comment: @ekhumoro I was already happy with your answer and my inattention, but nothing has changed.